# Setting a "Read More" button url to an altered form of a permalink

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress theme which has a slider with 8 different links. When clicked, the homepage expands for a summary and a "Read More" button appears.  The read more grabs the permalink from the post and sends you there.

Example: Livewasteless.com/assess/

For text formatting purposes I want to point it to a page rather than a post, so I want the "Read More" button url to include /read-more/

Example: Livewasteless.com/read-more/assess

```
        <!-- MORE -->               
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="more-slide">Read More</a>

        <div class="bvk-slide-content-close">

            X

        </div>
```

I have tried to find the Wordpress file that `the_permalink()` is referring to with no luck so far.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace mode:

```
<?php echo str_replace(".com/", ".com/read-more/", get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>
```

**.com is your tld, and $post->id must get the ID of the post.*

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you for the response. I now have    '<a href="<?php str_replace(".com/", ".com/read-more/", get_permalink()); ?>" class="more-slide">Read More</a>'    but it isn't working.  I'm very new to php. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Ah-ha! I added print_r in front, works now! This is the feeling I love about learning to code! Thanks again!

Comment: in your first comment you omissed to echo, check my answer